# SharePoint Library Search Doesn't Work For ID

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

In SharePoint 2013 the inline/insitu list search doesn't search by List Item ID - is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some quick testing on both a SharePoint 2013 on-premises farm and SharePoint Online, it should work if you use the correct Keyword Query Language (KQL) property restriction syntax and the search schema configuration hasn't been modified from the default.

The search configuration point that is critical here is the Managed Property called "ListItemId".  This maps to a Crawled Property called "ows_ListItemId". Thus, your query should be:

```
ListItemId:X
```

where X is the Id you are looking for.

For example, the screenshot below is an on-premises document library where I'm looking for an Id of 6.

[image]

And this screenshot is of an asset library in SharePoint Online where I'm looking for an Id of 4.

[image]

Lastly, you should note that the "ListItemId" Managed Property is of the type Text so it will only support Text KQL operators.  Here's a link to more KQL details:

[Keyword Query Language (KQL) syntax reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Please note that everything that you see on screen is not searchable. The search that you are performing is using SharePoint search engine behind the scene.

SharePoint crawls the fields that are meant to be searchable and those that are marked as "Indexed = true". ID field is not indexed so you cannot perform ID based search.

UPDATE: If your library is more than 5000 items, you might as well be victim of stupid in-place search. Check my blog for interesting findings: http://the-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2015/12/strangeunexpectedfrustrating-in-place.html

Comment: Can ID be made an indexed field?

Answer (score 0):

was looking for an answer and found a Microsoft answer and i wanted to share.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sposupport/2017/12/28/searching-for-files-and-items-using-id-does-not-return-expected-results/

Comment: Hello Ivan, welcome to the community and thanks for sharing the information. But please include the necessary portion of the information in your answer because link-only answer will not help anyone if the link gets broken in future.